# How to add item in eclipse project explorer context menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Thanks in advance .....

I have to add one item in project explorer's context menu  (new->new item), and also in new toolbar's web category (new item) . I can directly add item in context menu , but how to add in New menu of the project explorer's context menu. Same for the new toolbar , i can directly add contents i

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use the 'org.eclipse.ui.newWizards' extension-point to contribute an new wizard, and then use the 'org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent'(common wizard) extension-point to add your wizard to the context menu.

Comment: This is exactly right. I had the same problem and what threw me was needing to use navigator extension point to change the Project Explorer menu.